# What's the default chromedriver commandtimeout value?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor_4.htm

Does anyone know what the default chromedriver commandtimeout value is? Did a google search but couldn't find out anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember Selenium is [open source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/).

The answer to your question can be found by inspecting the ChromeDriver [source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs#L59) to find out that if a `CommandTimeout` value is not given, it reverts to `RemoteWebDriver.DefaultCommandTimeout`, which we can [see](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L69) is **60 seconds**.

This is the same for all of the drivers (at least in the .NET library)