# How to scrape some links from a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying to parse the links ended with `20012019.csv` from a webpage using the below script but the thing is I'm always having `timeout exception` error. It occurred to me that I did things in the right way.

However, any insight as to where I'm going wrong will be highly appreciated.

My attempt so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices'

def get_info(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='20012019.csv']"):
        print(item.get_attribute("href"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        get_info(driver,url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: it worked without error for me, try `time.sleep()`

Comment: `Selenium` is overkill for this project. Have you considered using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: The content are dynamic so I highly doubt `requests` can handle them @nicholishen.

Comment: It's not dynamic, it streams a very large html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine (tried it and it works), the reason you get a timeout is because the default timeout is 60s according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555000/whats-the-default-chromedriver-commandtimeout-value) and the page is huge.

Add this to your code before making the `get` request (to wait 180s before timeout):

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(180)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the the *visibility of all elements located* and you need to change the line:

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='20012019.csv']"):
```

to:

```
for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='20012019.csv']"))):
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```