# Java selenium remotewebdriver set command timeout

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Simple task - in one screnario i need the page to stay idle for about 3-4 minutes, which is over the default command timeout. 
C# implementation of the `RemoteWebDriver` class have this setting `CommandTimeout` as an overloaded constructor param: [What's the default chromedriver commandtimeout value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555000/whats-the-default-chromedriver-commandtimeout-value)

Is there a way to set it with java `RemoveWebDriver` ? the default constructor doesn't have such arguments and  `WebDriver.Timeouts` doesn`t have such setting either. I use chromedriver with selenium hub.

Comment: Which _Timeout_ are you exactly looking for? _WebDriver.Timeouts_ or _RemoteWebDriver.CommandTimeout_ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter under which classname it is. I'm looking for the timeout setting which would set the webdriver's "command timeout" (this is not a particular parameter / class name). something similar with `RemoteWebDriver.CommandTimeout` which is available for `C#` implementation.